# How can we make passive out of perfect continuous tenses?

Tags: passive-voice, writing, sentence-patterns, active-voice, learning

Can we make passive out of perfect continuous tenses as below?

*English is being taught here since 2013*

*He is being beaten since morning*

*We are being taught this since February*

It's just that "has been being" sounds strange to me and I've heard from many teachers that we should avoid using this. I want know how native speaker would say the sentences above. How and why?

Comment: The Passive voice of a Present Perfect Continuous sentence sounds ugly, sounds verbose,  and sounds like something an AI might produce on command. Look up examples on the net, do they come from real life or from grammar books? [**It is being put out** …](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It+is+being+put+out%22&oq=%22It+is+being+put+out%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l3j33i22i29i30l4.12142j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) may be an exception to the rule but is nevertheless rare.

Comment: This sounds so much like French grammar. Unlike French, we don't use the present with *since*; these sentences sound even worse to me than the ugly *has been being* construction.

Answer (score 3):

No, don't use this construction!

Using *is being* with *since* sounds bad to native English speakers, as well as being grammatically wrong. Here are some better ways of rewording these sentences to avoid the ugly *has been being **verbed*** construction

> *English is being taught here since 2013,
> English has been taught here since 2013.

There's no need for the continuous aspect in that sentence.

> *He is being beaten since morning,
> He has been beaten continuously since morning.

Here (and in many similar sentences), you can replace the continuous aspect in the verb by the adverb *continuously* (or *continually*). It sounds much better.

> *We are being taught this since February.
> We have been learning this since February.

Switching form a passive verb to a corresponding active verb, if one exists, is another way of avoiding the passive perfect continuous tense.

> *This bridge is being repaired for the last ten years.
> This bridge has been under repair for the last ten years.

Switching from using a verb to a noun phrase with a similar meaning (if one exists) is another way to avoid this construction.

There are times when there is no good alternative to the passive perfect continuous tense. Feel free to use it in those cases.

Comment: Agreed, they sound like a poor translation from another language's syntax.